# Kotlin : How the default parameter in " fun main(parameters: Array<String>) " prints "guest" without assigning any values

Tags: android, kotlin

I am new to kotlin and I have a doubt on the "main" function. When I tried to print the first parameter inside the main function it returns as guest.

From where it returns and I have not assigned any values to the parameters in main function.

Any help should be a great support for my learning

```
fun main(parameters: Array<String>){
println("kudus, ${parameters[0]}")}
```

Output Obtained is :

```
kudus, guest
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you pass `guest` as parameters. If you tried it in o[nline compiler](https://try.kotlinlang.org/#/Examples/Hello,%20world!/Simplest%20version/Simplest%20version.kt), you will get `Exception in thread "main" .java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0`

```
fun main(parameters: Array<String>) {
    println("kudus, ${parameters[0]}")
}
```

Comment: You are rite @Joshua. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It’s not happening by default. Probably your IDE adds a parameter when starting the program. You’ve most certainly configured this at any time before. Check the Run config and remove the argument.